# Rotating ellipse in python using x,y,theta

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to draw an ellipse in python using the following equations:

```
xpos = a*np.cos(theta)
ypos = b*np.sin(theta)
```

[image: Ellipse]

This works, but when I try to rotate the resulting ellipse using:

```
xpos = xpos*np.cos(np.pi/2)+ypos*np.sin(np.pi/2)
ypos = -xpos*np.sin(np.pi/2)+ypos*np.cos(np.pi/2)
```

The ellipse becomes a line, rather than just rotated by 90 degrees. What is causing this?[image: Rotated ellipse]

Comment: A lot of missing code that one has to fill in... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're redefining `xpos` first and using that one for your new `ypos`, basically you're not doing the transformation of coordinates simultaneously.

If you create new variables for the points in the new coordinate system them you get the rotated ellipse.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
a = 1
b = 2

xpos = a*np.cos(theta)
ypos = b*np.cos(theta)

new_xpos = xpos*np.cos(np.pi/2)+ypos*np.sin(np.pi/2)
new_ypos = -xpos*np.sin(np.pi/2)+ypos*np.cos(np.pi/2)

plt.plot(xpos, ypos, 'b-')
plt.plot(new_xpos, new_ypos, 'r-')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone thinking there's something wrong with the code from @Ignacio, `ypos` should be, `ypos= b*np.sin(theta)`

Hence,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)

a = 1
b = 2

xpos = a*np.cos(theta)
ypos = b*np.sin(theta)

new_xpos = xpos*np.cos(np.pi/2)+ypos*np.sin(np.pi/2)
new_ypos = -xpos*np.sin(np.pi/2)+ypos*np.cos(np.pi/2)

plt.plot(xpos,ypos, 'b')
plt.plot(new_xpos,new_ypos, 'r')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```